Stripe Cloud Function taking an AGE to write to firestore
I currently have a google cloud function (below) that receives the webhook from stripe payments and writes some of this data to firestore. My issue however is that it seems to hang for around 3 minutes and eventually completes.
const Stripe = require("stripe");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2023-10-16",
});
if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}
const db = admin.firestore();

async function webhook(request, response) {
  const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      request.rawBody,
      sig,
      process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed.", err.message);
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed":
      handlepaymentCompletion(event.data.object);

      break;
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return response.status(400).end();
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({ received: true });
}

//  handle sub created

async function handlepaymentCompletion(payment) {
  try {
    const lineItems = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
      payment?.id,
      {
        limit: 100,
      }
    );
    console.log(lineItems.data);

    // // Transform line items data
    // const itemsToSave = lineItems.data.map((item) => ({
    //   amount: item.amount_total,
    //   currency: item.currency,
    //   description: item.description,
    //   active: item.price.active,
    //   created: item.price.created,
    //   product: item.price.product,
    // }));

    /// Assuming there's only one item
    const item = lineItems.data[0];

    // Construct the data object for Firestore
    const data = {
      amount: item.amount_total,
      currency: item.currency,
      description: item.description,
      active: item.price.active,
      created: payment.created,
      product: item.price.product,
      paymentIntentId: payment.payment_intent,
    };

    const customer_id = payment.customer;

    // Query for the client document with the matching `stripeCusId`
    const clientQuerySnapshot = await db
      .collection("productionClients")
      .where("stripeCustId", "==", customer_id)
      .get();

    if (!clientQuerySnapshot.empty) {
      const clientId = clientQuerySnapshot.docs[0].id;

      // Reference to the invoicePayments sub-collection
      const invoicePaymentsRef = db
        .collection("productionClients")
        .doc(clientId)
        .collection("invoicePayments");

      // Example: Here's how you could add a new invoice payment document
      invoicePaymentsRef.add(data);

      console.log("Invoice payment updated successfully.");
    } else {
      console.log("No client found with the specified Stripe customer ID.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating user:", error);
    // Optionally handle the error
  }
}

module.exports = webhook;


Function Logs
I have added additional logging and it appears that where the hang happens is the querying of the client document that matches the customer_id from stripe.
The collection has 4 items in it, so it is not in anyway a large collection or indexing issue.
I can't see any other issue that it would be.
Can anyone shed any light?

EDIT
Await was added back to line invoicePaymentsRef.add(data);
Still delays in writing to firestore.
Code with await
Log

You're missing await on the promise returned by add():
await invoicePaymentsRef.add(data);

All promises or other async work must be awaited or somehow fully resolved before the function returns, or you will get unexplained behavior like this.
See:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/avoiding-gcf-anti-patterns-part-4-how-handle-promises-correctly-your-nodejs-cloud-function
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions


Thanks Doug, the await was removed when debugging and never was readded. I can confirm that the issue still persists with the await on the promise.
